# Complex Condition in vectorization of Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I'm fairly new to Python and Pandas, so I'm still learning. I have a Dataframe that contains a bunch of OHLCV data, which is loaded into a Dataframe

```
                                          Timestamp       Open       High     Low   Close      Volume  Trades
Timestamp                                                                                                    
2015-08-07 14:03:00+00:00 2015-08-07 14:03:00+00:00    3.00000    3.00000    3.00    3.00   81.857278       2
2015-08-07 17:19:00+00:00 2015-08-07 17:19:00+00:00    3.00001    3.00001    3.00    3.00   42.073291       2
2015-08-08 06:43:00+00:00 2015-08-08 06:43:00+00:00    3.00000    3.00000    3.00    3.00    0.400000       1
2015-08-08 09:31:00+00:00 2015-08-08 09:31:00+00:00    2.00000    2.00000    2.00    2.00  125.000000       2
2015-08-08 16:30:00+00:00 2015-08-08 16:30:00+00:00    1.20000    1.20000    1.20    1.20   54.759700       1
...                                             ...        ...        ...     ...     ...         ...     ...
2020-12-31 23:55:00+00:00 2020-12-31 23:55:00+00:00  738.49000  738.49000  738.49  738.49    0.748789       3
2020-12-31 23:56:00+00:00 2020-12-31 23:56:00+00:00  738.07000  738.07000  737.72  737.72    2.491733       8
2020-12-31 23:57:00+00:00 2020-12-31 23:57:00+00:00  738.15000  738.15000  737.94  738.05   56.043875       9
2020-12-31 23:58:00+00:00 2020-12-31 23:58:00+00:00  738.14000  738.15000  737.55  737.75   80.826279      16
2020-12-31 23:59:00+00:00 2020-12-31 23:59:00+00:00  737.01000  737.60000  737.01  737.45    3.129885       8
```

As you can see, there are missing minutes between some of the entries, due to no actual volume happening in that minute. What I'm trying to do, is create a new column that has the previous minutes volume, if there is no row for the previous minute, then that value should be 0.

I was trying to use the following statement:

```py
df.loc[
    (df['Timestamp'].shift().notna() == True) & 
    (
        ((df['Timestamp'].shift().dt.minute.astype(int) == (df['Timestamp'].dt.minute.astype(int) - 1)) & (df['Timestamp'].dt.minute.astype(int) >= 2)) |
        ((df['Timestamp'].shift().dt.minute.astype(int) == 59) & (df['Timestamp'].dt.minute.astype(int) >= 2)) 
    ), 'previousVolume'] = df['Volume'].shift().astype(float)
```

For adding `0`s I would check for the negative of the above.

The error that I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "engulfing_test.py", line 145, in <module>
    ), 'previousVolume'] = df['Volume'].shift().astype(float)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/Personal/crypto-bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5877, in astype
    new_data = self._mgr.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/Personal/crypto-bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 631, in astype
    return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/Personal/crypto-bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 427, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/Personal/crypto-bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py", line 673, in astype
    values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)
  File "/Users/username/Projects/Personal/crypto-bot/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py", line 1068, in astype_nansafe
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer")
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer
```

I know complex statements like this work, cause doing something like this works:

```
df.loc[(df['Timestamp'].dt.minute.astype(int) > 10) & (df['Timestamp'].dt.minute.astype(int) < 57), 'gt10lt57'] = 'Yes'
```

Any help greatly appreciated

**EDIT**

Adding output of `print(df.head().to_dict())`

```
{'Timestamp': {Timestamp('2015-08-07 14:03:00+0000', tz='UTC'): Timestamp('2015-08-07 14:03:00+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-08-07 17:19:00+0000', tz='UTC'): Timestamp('2015-08-07 17:19:00+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-08-08 06:43:00+0000', tz='UTC'): Timestamp('2015-08-08 06:43:00+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-08-08 09:31:00+0000', tz='UTC'): Timestamp('2015-08-08 09:31:00+0000', tz='UTC'), Timestamp('2015-08-08 16:30:00+0000', tz='UTC'): Timestamp('2015-08-08 16:30:00+0000', tz='UTC')}, 'Open': {Timestamp('2015-08-07 14:03:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 3.0, Timestamp('2015-08-07 17:19:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 3.00001, Timestamp('2015-08-08 06:43:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 3.0, Timestamp('2015-08-08 09:31:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 2.0, Timestamp('2015-08-08 16:30:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 1.2}, 'High': {Timestamp('2015-08-07 14:03:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 3.0, Timestamp('2015-08-07 17:19:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 3.00001, Timestamp('2015-08-08 06:43:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 3.0, Timestamp('2015-08-08 09:31:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 2.0, Timestamp('2015-08-08 16:30:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 1.2}, 'Low': {Timestamp('2015-08-07 14:03:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 3.0, Timestamp('2015-08-07 17:19:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 3.0, Timestamp('2015-08-08 06:43:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 3.0, Timestamp('2015-08-08 09:31:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 2.0, Timestamp('2015-08-08 16:30:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 1.2}, 'Close': {Timestamp('2015-08-07 14:03:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 3.0, Timestamp('2015-08-07 17:19:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 3.0, Timestamp('2015-08-08 06:43:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 3.0, Timestamp('2015-08-08 09:31:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 2.0, Timestamp('2015-08-08 16:30:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 1.2}, 'Volume': {Timestamp('2015-08-07 14:03:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 81.85727776, Timestamp('2015-08-07 17:19:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 42.07329055, Timestamp('2015-08-08 06:43:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 0.4, Timestamp('2015-08-08 09:31:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 125.0, Timestamp('2015-08-08 16:30:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 54.7597}, 'Trades': {Timestamp('2015-08-07 14:03:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 2, Timestamp('2015-08-07 17:19:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 2, Timestamp('2015-08-08 06:43:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 1, Timestamp('2015-08-08 09:31:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 2, Timestamp('2015-08-08 16:30:00+0000', tz='UTC'): 1}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `asfreq`

First, get rid of the duplicate `Timestamp` column that is identical to the index.
Leave the index where it is.  `asfreq` will change the frequency of the index.

```
df.drop('Timestamp', axis=1).asfreq('min', fill_value=0)

                             Open    High     Low   Close     Volume  Trades
Timestamp                                                                   
2015-08-07 14:03:00+00:00    3.00    3.00    3.00    3.00  81.857278       2
2015-08-07 14:04:00+00:00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.000000       0
2015-08-07 14:05:00+00:00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.000000       0
2015-08-07 14:06:00+00:00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.000000       0
2015-08-07 14:07:00+00:00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   0.000000       0
...                           ...     ...     ...     ...        ...     ...
2020-12-31 23:55:00+00:00  738.49  738.49  738.49  738.49   0.748789       3
2020-12-31 23:56:00+00:00  738.07  738.07  737.72  737.72   2.491733       8
2020-12-31 23:57:00+00:00  738.15  738.15  737.94  738.05  56.043875       9
2020-12-31 23:58:00+00:00  738.14  738.15  737.55  737.75  80.826279      16
2020-12-31 23:59:00+00:00  737.01  737.60  737.01  737.45   3.129885       8

[2841717 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Am I still able to access the index the same way?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me when I add that statement. Wouldn't I just use `drop`? `df = df.drop(['Timestamp'], axis=1)`

Comment: I get the following error when doing `asfreq`

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "engulfing_test.py", line 122, in <module>
    df.asfreq('min', fill_value=0)
    ....
    TypeError: value should be a 'Timestamp' or 'NaT'. Got 'int' instead.

Comment: When doing `print(df.index)`

DatetimeIndex(['2015-08-07 14:03:00+00:00', '2015-08-07 17:19:00+00:00',
               '2015-08-08 06:43:00+00:00', '2015-08-08 09:31:00+00:00',
               ...
               '2020-12-31 23:56:00+00:00', '2020-12-31 23:57:00+00:00',
               '2020-12-31 23:58:00+00:00', '2020-12-31 23:59:00+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', name='Timestamp', length=1678578, freq=None)

Comment: run this `df.head().to_dict()` and update your question with the results.

Comment: ok, I got the error.  let me figure that out.

Comment: It's because you still have the `Timestamp` column.  I was more explicit in my answser.

Comment: Ah my bad, I was removing it after.

Comment: Lol, now I can't access `df['Timestamp']`, but I'll figure that out. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: No worries.  We got it sorted out.